# "Fade-ins" (digital marketing)

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

What is the meaning of "fade-ins" in the following sentence found in a data protection agreement?

"We use Ad Server Cookies to measure ***fade-ins*** of advertisements and clicks."

Comment: Exactly that - that the item fades into view from being invisible and hidden, to fully visible on the screen. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y0a-RUc2hlY) on YouTube shows a fade from green to black, imagine this but something appearing from nowhere :)

Comment: Ivan, many web sites get money by showing you ads. Some money if you click on an ad link, and also if you go to a web page and you can't see it yet, because an ad fades in and it takes some time like 30 seconds before you can click a button to close it. The ad server wants to know what ads you have already seen and what links you have clicked.

Answer (score 0):

'[Fade-in](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/fade-in)':

> a gradual increase in the visibility of a scene

I get the confusion, as it seems the fade-ins themselves are measured using your cookies, but the idea is that these advertisements are fading in and out of view on your screen, and some metric must be involved to correlate an ad's visibility to its revenue, and this depends on your screen time.